# conexion mysql php remotamente

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

buen dia tengo un problema
quiero conectarme a mi propio worbench por medio de la ip
el problema es que tengo xampp en otro piso del edificio donde si me agrran los sitios web
pero necesito conectarme a mi maquina donde esta mysql

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1130): Host '10.100.14.10' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in C:\xampp\htdocs\convenios\admin.php on line 7
Connection failed: Host '10.100.14.10' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: Saludos. Realiza una prueba en una de las computadoras en la misma red y piso donde esta el MySQL al que quieres conectarte, puede ser que tengas para todo o el usuario que usas no permita conexiones remotas y eso sea la restricción; otra, es que "no alcances" al servidor por estar en otra red/subnet; digamos que sean redes aisladas y por tanto no se ven los equipos; un ping hacia el equipo donde esta MySQL sería lo 1ro a revisar responde.

Comment: has de cuenta los de redes las tienen separadas por pisos 
aqui esta xampp ->piso 8- piso 7 - piso 6--piso5--piso4 -> aqui estoy-piso3-piso2

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Los dos escenarios "básicos" que pueden estar afectando asumiendo no hay error en las credenciales que usas son (sin orden de importancia/relevancia/etc alguno): **1.-** El servidor no permite conexiones remotas (que este deshabilitados para todos y/o el usuario que usas). **2.-** Que aún estando en la misma red de la compañia/edificio o lo que sea existan restricciones para acceder a equipos de las redes en cada edificio/piso (esto *lo validas* haciendo ping hacia la IP/Host que deseas conectarte).

Comment: si las hay pero has de cuenta en el piso de xampp solo lo uso para ver la pagina web y en mi maquina esta mysql y mi maquina esta abierta a todo debo de conectarme del piso de xampp a mi maquina

Comment: ya quedo gracioas